# knockout accessing observable from a function

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I am confused about this problem. Knockout uses `ko.applyBindings()` method to update MVVM pattern. At the below code you can see my functions. Firstly I create an empty **vm** then I call other functions to fill the data via `getJSON()` method. Methods are working fine.

```
var vm = {};
function GetData(){
  vm=GetMockData();
  LoadUserData();
  LoadCategories();
  LoadSkills();
  return vm;
}
```

My confusion starts here, my job is to store this **values according to user input.**

```
 <input data-bind='' placeholder="Enter your name"/>
```

At the top HTML section I want to bind that value to like;`GetMockData().obj.User.Name`. But not working.

```
function GetMockData(){
    var obj={
        User:{
            Name: ko.observable().extend({
                required: true,
                minLength: 2,
                maxLength: 15
            }),
            Surname: "Fake Surname"
        }
    return obj;
}
```

And for `applyBindings()` I call the below code section.

```
ko.applyBindings(new GetData());
```

I am confused at the below part. To get a `User.Name` from a function, that called by another function, because I am reaching that part not directly from `applyBindings()` but from another function. ***How should I call it write data-bind value to HTML?***

```
<input data-bind='' placeholder="Enter your name"/>
```

Comment: You should try to use a more standard (class) pattern to initialize your viewmodel. Right now, there's no point in using the `new` keyword, since you're mutating and returning a global variable. Other than that: the binding context is `vm`, which means your data-bind can be `data-bind="textInput: User.Name"`

Comment: thank you I did it like what you said and it worked perfect !

Answer (score 0):

At first I was very confused by what you were actually getting at here. Even at this point I'm still not entirely sure. But here is my best attempt to help you.

The main problem you're looking to solve, as I understand it, is a matter of what's called "hydration". Which is a lazily executed process to fill something with something else. You can also see it as a means of "resetting" the state of something. Below is a snippet of how I might solve this problem, exemplifying both sides of hydration.

**JavaScript**

```
function User() {
    var self = this;

    self.Name = ko.observable().extend({
        required: true,
        minLength: 2,
        maxLength: 15
    });

    self.Surname = ko.observable();

    self.Hydrate = function(){ 
        self.Surname("Fake SureName"); 
    };
};

function AppModel(){
    var self = this;

    self.User = {};

    self.Hydrate = function(){
        var user = new User();
        user.Hydrate();
        self.User = user;
    };
};

var app = new AppModel();
app.Hydrate();
ko.applyBindings(app);
```

Now that we have the JavaScript side nailed down, let's move on to the DOM. In order to receive input from the user in a text field you have two main options: `value` and `textInput`. `value` updates the observable on the blur event, `textInput` on the keyup. You can decide which serves you best.

**HTML**

```
<input data-bind="textInput: User.Name" placeholder="Enter your name"/>
```

It's important to note that if you're looking to scale this solution, it's best to apply your view model functions (not observables) to the prototype of your class. Like so:

```
function AppModel(){
    var self = this;

    self.User = {};
};

AppModel.prototype.Hydrate = function(){
    var self = this;

    var user = new User();

    self.User(user);
};
```

As a side note, from looking at your code, it seems you might lack a bit of understanding on how to "put together" a knockout solution. I would highly recommend checking out the [tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/) offered on the knockout website to get a better sense of architecture. Also this [video](https://vimeo.com/51103092), by Ryan Niemeyer a member of the knockout team, is old but still extremely relevant.

Comment: thanks for the info, but with the comment that made in to my question i solved the issue, I dont want to add more things to my js file as it is already confusing. This knockout confusing me as hell thanks for the video source too